# How to limit the users in LDAP to logon to a specific subset of Linux machines

Tags: linux, ldap

Scenario:

We have user user1, user2, user3 and user4 in LDAP. And Linux machines linux1, linux2, linux3, linux4, ... linux50 is in this LDAP domain.

Now the problem is:

How to limit user1 to only have permission to logon linux1, linux2, linux3, and linux 4 only? The other users (user2, user3, user4) can logon to all of these machines (this is trivial, we already have it).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to create two LDAP groups, e.g. "tester" and "developer", or whatever.

Then on linux2, linux3, and linux4, you would add

```
pam_groupdn "developers"
```

to `/etc/ldap.conf`.

See http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_ldap for more details.